# Concat two arrays which one of them is also an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

How do I concat two arrays which one of them is also an array. It looks like this

```js
let stat = [
  ["completed", "0", "0", "0"],
  ["due", "1", "2", "2"],
  ["warning", "0", "0", "0"]
]

let val = [
  [0, 0, 0],
  [1, 2, 2],
  [0, 0, 0]
]



var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < stat.length; i++) {
  var temp = [stat[i][0].concat([val[i]])];
  arr.push(temp);
}
console.log(arr)
```

When console.log, it will print out:

```
["Completed0,0,0"]
["Due1,2,2"]
["Warning0,0,0"]
```

and I want the result looks like this:

```
["Completed", 0, 0, 0]
["Due", 1, 2, 2]
["Warning", 0, 0, 0]
```

How can I get new array like that? Thank you!

Comment: please add the wanted result which reflects the given data.

Comment: how the end result is 0,0,0 for all?

Comment: There's probably a left-over `"` at the end of the last line of the desired result. Please **[edit]** the question and fix it.

Comment: Please explain the need for this? If you just loop and +val each digit, you do not need the second array to get to the desired output, or did you meant to have `let stat = [
  ["completed"],
  ["due"],
  ["warning"]
]` to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a string result in the array, because you take the first item of the array and use `concat`, which works for strings ([`String#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat)) as well as for arrays ([`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)), but in case of a string, the parameter is converted to string. The result is a sting, not single values of an array.

```js
var stat = [["completed", "0", "0", "0"], ["due", "1", "2", "2"], ["warning", "0", "0", "0"]],
    val = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0]],
    arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < stat.length; i++) {
    var temp = [stat[i][0]].concat(val[i]);
    arr.push(temp);
}
console.log(arr)
```

A shorter approach is to map the first item with the values of `val`.

```js
var stat = [["completed", "0", "0", "0"], ["due", "1", "2", "2"], ["warning", "0", "0", "0"]],
    val = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0]],
    result = stat.map(([v], i) => [v, ...val[i]]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
let stat = [
  ["completed", "0", "0", "0"],
  ["due", "1", "2", "2"],
  ["warning", "0", "0", "0"]
]

let val = [
  ["0", "0", "0"],
  ["1", "2", "2"],
  ["0", "0", "0"]
]


var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < stat.length; i++) {
  var temp = stat[i].concat(
    val[i].filter(x => !stat[i].includes(x))
  );
  arr.push(temp);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on [mplungjan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137189/concat-two-arrays-which-one-of-them-is-also-an-array/55137250#comment97015249_55137189), why not using only one array?

```js
stats = [
  ["completed", "0", "0", "0"],
  ["due", "1", "2", "2"],
  ["warning", "0", "0", "0"]
];

stats2 = stats.map(function (x) {
  return [
    x[0],
    parseInt(x[1], 10),
    parseInt(x[2], 10),
    parseInt(x[3], 10)
  ];
});

for (i = 0; i < stats2.length; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(stats2[i]));
}
```

Comment: I've look for how to parse those number without slice the array but I can't find the way. So I sliced it first, parse, and then concat them.
Thank you for helping me again!